# How to "achieve" this glowing affect in android?

Tags: android, xml, drawable, glow

I am trying to do a background for listview items similar to this one. That blue line which indicates selected item has glowing affect on it. I want that:

[image]

What I am able to get is something like this:

[image]

I have been looking for a solution for about 3 hours now, so help would be greatly appreciated. How to achieve it? Here is what I have come up with in my drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_brown" />
            <size android:width="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="5dp"
        android:right="180dp">

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/dark_brown"
                android:endColor="@color/text_light"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/text_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: you could use a 9patch

Comment: any other way possible?

Comment: "glowing" , you mean appearing and disappearing ?

Comment: I think he/she means the shade on the right side of the vertical blue bar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is a gradient on the right of your solid bar that fades either to transparent or the background color of your cell. You'll want to tweak the size of it, and maybe add a centerColor to get it to look just right, but that should get you closer to what you're looking for.

As wrecker mentioned, you could also use an image for this (like a 9-patch)